# Removing duplicates in an Array, why this code is not working

Tags: javascript

Hi I have written below code

```
function unique(th){
   var obj = {};
   for(var i = 0, n = th.length; i < n ; i++){
       obj[th[i]] = th[i];
   }    
   obj.length = n ;
   return Array.prototype.slice.call(obj);
}
```

But, this is giving me unwanted output. Please help me to correct this. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NSjnY/) is the fiddle.

Comment: Why downvote..? I have written unwanted output. Not unwanted and something....

Comment: @Adnan Shammout Hmm ok, but thanks :-) Even downvotes helped this time...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what was your logic so I build a slightly different and working function, trying to make it as clear as possible :

```
function unique(th){
   var yetseen = {};
   var newarray = [];
   for(var i = 0, n = th.length;  i < n ; i++){
       var val = th[i];
       if (!yetseen[val]) {
           yetseen[val] = true;
           newarray.push(val);
       }
   }    
   return newarray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

It's a library with a host of functions for manipulating arrays.

### [_.uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq)

> _.uniq(array, [isSorted], [iterator]) Alias: unique  Produces a
>   duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object
>   equality. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing
>   true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to
>   compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iterator
>   function.

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mJ73d/)

`alert(_.uniq([2,2,1,4,5,6,2,9,1,1,6,3,2,1,9,6,4], false)​);​ //yields 2,1,4,5,6,9,3`

Comment: Thanks for referring underscore.js

Comment: @SoI - Just discovered it a month or so ago. Been loving it ever since!